# Getting warning on elements with "btn-normal" class

Tags: css, visual-studio-2013, warnings

I've searched all around but haven't come across with anybody else getting this warning. I'm using Visual Studio 2013 Professional. I've got a class called `btn-normal` that I assign to my standard buttons in my web application. Whenever I build the project, along with other warnings I get this one:

> When using "btn-normal", you must also specify the class "btn".

I've tried searching my entire solution for "btn-normal" but I haven't found anything else than what I've specified in my CSS file. I know it's a minor thing but it is still annoying. Does anybody know why I get this warning?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I finally found it. After googling around for `btn-` I realized that bootstrap button classes are prefixed the same way. (Look [here](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_buttons.asp) for bootstrap buttons. )And I have Web essentials in my Visual Studio and it by default validates any html against Bootstrap naming conventions.(At least this is what I assume is the case.) After turning this option off and restarting the IDE I got rid of the warning. To turn it off go to Tools->Options->WebEssentials->HTML. Under Misc set `Enable Bootstrap validation` to `False`. Do not forget to restart the IDE.

Comment: Good catch - this is likely to bother others too.

Answer (score 0):

You must declare your button like this:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-normal">
```

Comment: But why? According to which html/css rules?